# Type declaration in Java

Tags: java

Say `Iterator<Integer> sth = sth2.sfunc;`

I am wondering what is `<Integer>` here? Does it mean an integer list of an iterator or what?

Comment: @tbraun89 let JavaDoc 1.4 die, link to newer Docs.

Comment: Take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html

Answer (score 4):

It's an example of [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) being used to increase [type safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). `Iterator` is a parameterized type, and in this case, `Integer` is used as its type parameter.

The effect is simply that the compiler knows that the `next()` method of an `Iterator<Integer>` always returns an `Integer`, so you don't have to cast it explicitly (the compiler will do that for you), and you'll get a compiler error if you accidentally try to cast it to `String` - with a pre-generics `Iterator` whose `next()` method returns `Object` this would not be noticed until runtime.

Comment: To be clear, an `Iterator<Integer>` should be interpreted as an iterator over a collection of `Integer`s.

Answer (score 1):

its `generics` in java for `type safety` in collections...So in your case only `<Integer>` value you can add and retrive from colections...And `Iterator<Integer>` Always return an Integer...

see here ....  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html